# RegGetValue vs RegQueryValueEx

Tags: windows, registry

I have a program coded by someone else. It has a function RegGetValue used as:

```
 uFuncReturnValue = RegOpenKeyExA(  HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, 
                                acSubKey, 
                                NULL, 
                                KEY_READ | KEY_WRITE,
                                    &hRegistry
                                    ); 

  //Store signature of the disk in the first 32 bytes of structVal
 if( uFuncReturnValue != ERROR_SUCCESS )
            {
            printf("Unable to open registry with error %u\n", uFuncReturnValue);
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);;
            }

uFuncReturnValue = RegGetValueA( hRegistry, 
                        NULL, 
                        "\\DosDevices\\C:",  
                        RRF_RT_REG_BINARY, 
                        NULL, 
                        (LPVOID)&structVal, 
                        &dwSize
                        );
```

This block of code works perfectly on Windows 7 but returns error when run on Windows XP (32 bit). As 32-bit xp don't have **RegGetValue** function so I am trying to make use of **RegQueryValueEX** but I am having problem in passing arguments to this function. I think it should be used some thing like:

```
uFuncReturnValue = RegQueryValueExA ( hRegistry, 
                                  "\\DosDevices\\J:",
                                  NULL,
                                  NULL,
                                  (LPBYTE) &structVal,
                                  &dwSize
                                  );
```

But something is wrong here because the code compiles successfully but when I execute it I get a message:

> The program '(128) myProgram.exe:
>   Native' has exited with code 1 (0x1).

Can someone help me here please?

Comment: What is `dwSize` set to when you call `RegQueryValueEx`? Is it set to `sizeof structVal`?

Comment: And is that the same as the size of `structVal`? The last parameter of RegQueryValueEx is both input and output. For input, it must be set to the size of the buffer pointed to by the previous parameter. On output, it contains the number of bytes copied (it may be different than the buffer size).

Comment: structVal has been declared like this: struct partitionInfo structVal;

Comment: Yes, but what is the size of `structVal`? You should do `dwSize = sizeof structVal;` to make sure that `dwSize` is set correctly before it is passed to `RegQueryValueEx`.

Comment: Thanks dreamlax. There was no problem with the code. Problem lied in one of a file from which I was reading some data. Sorry to bother you.